# Get public key from SSH server

Tags: ssh, certificate, rsa, modulo

I have been looking for this for a long time.

I need to extract and get the modulus and the exponent from an SSH server.

For example, I know, that SSH is running on server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (I can connect to this server / ping) but I don't know the user name and the password so I cannot log in.

I need to get the modulus and the exponent of the public RSA key of this server.

I found out, that `ssh-keyscan` can get modulus + exponent (from documentation) but only if ssh-rsa1 is used. If I try to get ssh-rsa(2) public key with ssh-keyscan, I cannot retrieve the modulus and the exponent from the output.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you ask. What do you want with the public key stored on a server? It won't give you access to that system. Since you need the private key for that.

Comment: I know. It is for my bachelor thesis. Need collect some public keys and .... :)

Comment: Well, just create some then.

Comment: It have to be a real (used) RSA pub key.

Comment: What is different with them?, compared to ones you generate? What makes them "real"? I mean they are just a series of numbers...

Comment: There is a different. I need to compare public key used on server, for example, if you are generating public key, what is probablity that 2 keys are same ? Or 2 different keys have commont prime factor ? this probablity is very near to 0... But if you have public key from some set of servers, for example 20 000 000, you could chcek, if 2 different servers is using same public (private) key, you could analyse it, how it is possible or what this 2 servers have common. Also, I'm collecting public keys with IP address, so I can look (check) that for example github have same public key as xxx.org

Comment: And, at least, I can see, what exponent is used. (not only 65537 is used). Next, I can check length of modulus. Maybe I can get some public key only 1024 bits length (or 512). Is it enough to get real used public key as generating some ? For statistic usage...

Comment: What you describe are well known attack vectors. But you should do some moth to find out about the probabilities that you actually find a match. You won't, unless for extremely old and short keys. But even if you would, that knowledge is worthless, since you do not have the matching private key.

Comment: I dont even need private keys. If I found 2 same public key, it is possible to use it as attack, but, I'm doing this for my bachelor thesis, not for attacting some ssh server (for what ? ... ) And I can also run to calculate GCD for every public key pair, which can be used for factoring and getting private key

Comment: LOL, sure, sounds like an interesting work!

Comment: Done, some public key are factored ! And also factored public key from SSL protocol ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure you can!

Download public key from github and save it into github.pub file:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | sed "s/^[^ ]* //" > github.pub
```

Convert SSH public key format into X.509 public key format:

```
ssh-keygen -f github.pub -e -m pem > github.pem
```

Parse ASN.1 encoding of key to obtain public key modulus and exponent:

```
sed "/--/d" github.pem | openssl asn1parse | grep "INTEGER" | sed "s/.*://"
```

Result:

```
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
23
```

First line is a modulus and second line is an exponent.

Comment: So for Azure Repos this would be `ssh-keyscan -t rsa vs-ssh.visualstudio.com | sed "s/^[^ ]* //" > vs-ssh.pub`.